# What languages does Weaviate support?

Tags: weaviate

I'm getting started with Weaviate, I visited the Weaviate docs, but I couldn't find a resource describing which languages are currently supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Programming languages**
Weaviate itself is written in Go, but most likely this has no influence on how you interact with it. Weaviate can be used language-agnostic using it's GraphQL and/or REST API. Additionally there are native language clients for Python, Go, Java and Javascript/Node. Other clients may be added in the future and if your favorite language is missing, you can contribute a client yourself.

**Human languages / NLP**
Weaviate Core (the pure database) is language-agnostic, it only knows objects and vectors. However, you might be interacting with Weaviate with one of our modules and they each support different languages, outlined below.

**Text2vec-transformers / multi2vec-clip**
You can plug in any transformers model, public or private, so there is no limitation to languages. The out-of-the-box models are typically either English or Multi-lingual

**QnA-transformers**
Similarly, the QnA module supports any custom module, so if you can find one in the language of your choice you can plug it in or train one yourself. The out-of-the-box modules currently all run in English.

**Text2vec-contextionary**
The contextionary models cannot be replaced with custom models, therefore you are limited to the out-of-the-box languages which currently include English, Dutch, German, Czech, Italian.

**Text-Spellcheck**
The spell-check module currently supports English, Dutch, and German, whereas also see https://ukatie.com/#/read-answer?domain-id=ceb2d2f2-2c1d-49be-a751-eed4be19e021&uuid=511aa289-361f-4b39-bbd0-84d286645f20